# sendUserActionEvent() mView== null after clicking on button

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I have checked with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null) but there its mentioned about long clicks. but I am facing this after clicking on button of custom dialog. 
I have pasted my code over here. can anyone help me to avoid this error.

```
  ibtnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("DemoDvicetracker", etConfirmPassword
                .getText().toString());
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                etConfirmPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);

            passwordPopup.dismiss();

        }
        });
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/rel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@drawable/popup_bg" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_enter_pwd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/enter_pwd"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_enter_pwd"
    android:hint="@string/pwd" 
    android:background="@drawable/popup_textfeild"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtn_dialog_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_cancel_selector" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/cancel"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibtn_dialog_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_submit_selector" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/submit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue, did you solved the issue ...

Comment: @kumarsu: No not yet. but I got it on note 8 as well.

Comment: What is mView in your code. I do not see it in the attached sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sendUserActionEvent() is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null)

Comment: Check my answer in this link, it may solve your problem: <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016155/senduseractionevent-mview-null-on-samsung-tab3/40619021#40619021

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this is not a problem related to your code, but related to S4 android version.
Same question has been posed on stackoverflow : [sendUserActionEvent() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null)

So, just ignore it ;)

Comment: Yes I have checked with that code as well and I am not only getting this ons4 but also getting this on note8.

Comment: I think this is due to the Samsung android layer which should be the same between S4 and note8.

Comment: Do you have any reference material for the same

Comment: Just my Samsung Galaxy S4 : GT-I9505, Android version 4.3, Version I9505XXUEMKF, Kernel version 3.4.0-2082040

Comment: I have asked about Samsung android layer which u have mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yeah, its name is TouchWiz, and the version is mentioned in my comment : Version 4.3-I9505XXUEMKF

Comment: This also happens on Galaxy S3 with 4.3-JSS15J.I9300XXUGMK6 firmware.

Comment: the same on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 -android 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using al this intent flags together to intent the activity:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Just left the clear_top flag and it solved the problem:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```