# sendUserActionEvent() mView==null on Samsung Tab3

Tags: android, bitmap, samsung-mobile

I am trying to preview an image after capturing it using camera from inside my app, I am sure the path is not null but I am  receiving this error in this line of code `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),options);` and there is no image view. Note: I tested the code on another device (not Samsung) and it works.

Answer (score 5):

I found a fix for this problem. Unfortunately, on some Samsung devices there is a problem with the built-in camera app that it causes screen rotation which leads to restarting your activity. For that `mView` becomes null. This happens also with other intents in samsung, not only in the camera. To fix it, you have to add this line in your manifest under your activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Google mentions in the [documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20120130201824/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "**screen size**" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the `"screenSize"` value in addition to the `"orientation"` value. That is, you must declare `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

Answer (score 3):

In regards to the `sendUserActionEvent() mView==null`, it is a know bug with Samsung devices (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160737/senduseractionevent-mview-null-after-clicking-on-button) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null)).

If it works on non-Samsung devices, then it is not your fault, it is Samsung's.
However, you should try and find a workaround if you can.
Again, it isn't your fault, it is a bug with TouchWiz.

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with this error for days, this happens because Samsung Camera app is by default in Landscape mode.

If you start camera app from an activity in Portrait mode, when it comes back from Landscape it calls automatically again OnCreate, that's why your path is null.

I solved this by adding a static counter into the activity if it is equal to 0 app call oncreate and did it all, if it is greater  than 0 loads only layout.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's correct.

What AJ has mentioned is the solution:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

It also solves another issue that arises due to calling the OnCreateView method every time the phone is rotated; helps prevent different edit fields from reverting to their original values, provided you have used `onSaveInstance()` to store your initial values. You can refer to this video here for that-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K_qlNluW38&index=67&list=PLHs_NFdr_LaHmEh7hV-wPyS-gKnAVPzBU