# Android: Can I ignore the errors " Parent view is not a TextView " and " sendUserActionEvent() mView == null "?

Tags: android, logcat

In my Android app, I am constantly getting the following two errors in my logcat:

```
06-02 20:33:16.070: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(13983): Parent view is not a TextView
06-02 20:33:12.010: E/ViewRootImpl(13983): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

My app runs completely fine in spite of these two errors, and I've found no definitive answer as to whether or not they are harmful (or even fixable!) errors or if they can be safely ignored. Thus far I've been doing fine just ignoring them, but I wanted this to be asked since I'm sure I am not the only one confused as to what these two errors mean.

For reference, I am getting these errors while running the app via adb on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

EDIT: The Parent view is not a TextView error happens at many times, but notably it happens whenever I press the back button on the action bar and when I start a new activity by pressing a button. I'm using the support library, minSdk=8.

Comment: Any idea what code is causing this error? In regard to `sendUserActionEvent()` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160737/senduseractionevent-mview-null-after-clicking-on-button and I recall getting that one many times and never worried about it. I'm not so sure about the `Parent View ...` though

Comment: I'll look at that, thanks! As far as the Parent view thing goes, it always happens when I press the back button on the action bar (I'm using the support library), and occasionally at other times

Comment: It's been a few months since I've worked on Android, but it doesn't look like an error that you are causing or that needs fixing. You could always test in the emulator or another device (preferably other manufacturers) which would help confirm it's a device problem.

Comment: I get the error too, on startup of my app on Galaxy S5.  Doesn't appear to hurt anything.  But, it's an error and leaves me worried something else will eventually break if just ignored.

Comment: Same error. Here is another question I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760745/what-the-logcat-message-e-moreinfohpw-viewgroup2905-parent-view-is-not-a-te
Alas, also no answer. What is this nonsense? I am testing on the 'GALAXY J SC-02F'

Comment: We need some code to have an idea to what's happening. But like Jakar said, some errors don't need fix

Comment: Are you using custom views in the actionbar or just setting actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); ?

Comment: android throws errors **all the time**..this is one of them..so be prepared to be alot worried..

Comment: Yes (if you're using Samsung).  This is a known issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null

Comment: What a peculiar error about the Parent view not being a TextView. As far as my understanding goes about Views, and Parent views, I don't see how TextView could ever be a Parent, as TextView doesn't extend ViewGroup.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can ignore, it's a known issue with Samsung models. If it bothers you, maybe you can replace

```
context.startActivity(....);
```

with:

```
startActivity(new Intent(....));
```

and see if it works for you too, as indicated in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592235/3202370

I hope it helps.