# What the logcat message: "E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(2905): Parent view is not a TextView" means?

Tags: android, view, logcat

I'm developing an android app, and I put a filter in my logcat to filter logs by my application package name. Unfortunately, this error message always appear and I don't know how to fix it. My app works well, without any problem or crash. However I want to fix this error log.

```
07-15 11:14:48.808: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(2905): Parent view is not a TextView
```

Comment: Probably you have casted a View to a TextView. Maybe if you post the code that print this error we can help you;)

Comment: @axl The code that prints the Log is not a part of the code I developed. My app is logging this, but I didn't write any code like:
    Log.e(TAG,"Message");

Comment: I noticed that the Log tag is "MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ignore this , it's a known issue with Samsung models.

Comment: probably samsung galaxy s3 and s4