# sendUserActionEvent() mView == null on clicking a menu item

Tags: java, android

I continue to get logcat error msgs when I tap on refresh menu item:

> com.example.android.sunshine.app W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to
>   finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been
>   disposed. com.example.android.sunshine.app E/ViewRootImpl:
>   sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

I am getting this error on Samsung J7 android version 5.1.1
I tried on nexus 7 as well and i got the following error every time I select menu items.

> finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been
>   disposed.

Here is my fragment code

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

/**
 * Created by Saumya on 2/10/2016.
 */

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecasts = {"Today-Sunny-88/63",
                "Tomorrow-Foggy-78/66",
                "Saturday-Cloudy-72/63",
                "Sunday-Rainy-74/61",
                "Monday-Foggy-70/46",
                "Tuesday-Sunny-76/68",
                "Tomorrow-Foggy-78/66",
                "Saturday-Cloudy-72/63",
                "Sunday-Rainy-74/61",
                "Monday-Foggy-70/46",
                "Tuesday-Sunny-76/68"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                forecasts);
        ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final String Log_Tag = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are available at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                String baseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=110077,in&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";
                String apiKey = "&APPID=" + BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY;
                URL url = new URL(baseUrl.concat(apiKey));
                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    //forecastJsonStr = null;
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    //forecastJsonStr = null;
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(Log_Tag, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
                //forecastJsonStr = null;
                return  null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(Log_Tag, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(Log_Tag, "Forecast JSON string" + forecastJsonStr);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_refresh){
            new FetchWeatherTask().execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160737/senduseractionevent-mview-null-after-clicking-on-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null

Comment: @Dhina I know its a specific samsung device problem but I want to know is there a way around it... i mean can i avoid this error?

Comment: @Dhina I tried on nexus 7.. still giving the same error