# Android error: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Tags: java, android

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == GALLERY){
        if (data != null) {

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
}
```

Comment: put the complete  logcat error here.

Comment: share your complete code where you define mView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sendUserActionEvent() mView== null after clicking on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160737/senduseractionevent-mview-null-after-clicking-on-button)

Answer (score 0):

Declare boolean and set as true

```
public boolean Counter = true;


public void setImage()
{
  while (Counter)
  continue;
  imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode == GALLERY){
    if (data != null) {

        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Counter = false;
    }
```

}