# Scan Barcode Within WebView Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to start the barcode scanner upon the user pressing a button in the html. However i am recieving an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scanBarcode'", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (49)
```

Which is being called in javascript with:

```
function scanner(){ 
        Android.scanBarcode();
    }
```

Now in the Java file i have the following code, which declares the function within`public class JavaScriptInterface`

Here is my `MainActivity.java` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    //myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    // Instantiate the interface and set the context
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    // using Javascript to call the finish activity
    public void closeMyActivity() {
        finish();
    }

    public void scanBarcode() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}   //JavascriptInterface

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //here is where you get your result
            String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is a code sample i found on the web, everything looks fine to me, the only thing i had to do initially was import all of the necessary libraries, and define the `barcode` variable to be of type string.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.. Or maybe a different method of accessing the barcode scanner functionality from a web view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
...
public class JavaScriptInterface {
```

You've called your interface class JavaScriptInterface, but created a new WebAppInterface to pass to the WebView.

#### Edit

The above answer still holds true: You never register the interface (JavaScriptInterface) with your WebView, so you will not have access to those methods (scanBarcode).

Since you actually need two interfaces in your WebView, you need to add both interfaces

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Scanner");
```

In your javascript you will have two objects `Android` and `Scanner` which correspond with the two interfaces. Android will have all the methods defined in WebAppInterface, while Scanner will have the methods defined in JavaScriptInterface. Your javascript function becomes

```
function scanner() {
    Scanner.scanBarcode();
}
```

#### Edit 2

If you are targeting sdk version 17 or above, you must also annotate the methods you want to use in your javascript

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
...
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void scanBarcode() {
    ...
    }
}
```

**Bonus**: A bit of unsolicited advice, use better names. If WebAppInterface provides methods for interacting with your application's data, call it DataInterface (even that is probably too generic, but I don't know what kind of data your app uses). Since JavaScriptInterface launches the scanner and closes the app, maybe you could call it ActionInterface. Passing those to your WebView as "AppData" and "AppActions" gives you functions like `AppData.getCategories()` and `AppActions.closeMyActivity()` which make more logical sense.

Comment: Yeas and then I have a file called `WebAppInterface.java`

In hear i have many functions that i call from my javascript like `Android.showCategories()` Is this where im going to have to call my barcode scan function, and not in the `MainActivity`
Which makes sense but then some of the default functions are not defined. such as `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` and a constant `RESULT_OK`

Any advice for this?

Comment: I move the previous code to the correct file and the applied to fix as described at the bottom of my question. I now have a different issue, so I have edited my question to show this.

Comment: You can define multiple interfaces, but you need to add them all individually and give them unique names. See my edit

Comment: @jburley89 That's not really how Stackoverflow works. Post a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for editing back then :)

I have tried adding a new `Scanner` as you mentioned, but I receive an 
`Cannot instantiate the type JavascriptInterface` error

Comment: Your class is called JavaScriptInterface, with a capital S

Comment: I still receive the same error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scanBarcode'", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (53)`
however, now i have notice that there is also `sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`

Comment: You can disregard sendUserActionEvent according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null If you are using targetSdk >= 17 you need to annotate your methods with `@JavascriptInterface`, just like you did in WebAppInterface

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I will now try and figure out why im getting `Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject`

I will add this as a different question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: i tried `((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult` which resulted in the same error..