# E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

Tags: java, android, pdf

i have this error:`E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`.
Why?

My Samsung Galaxy tab S2 has software version 6.0.1.

I hope that you can help me!

Thanks in advance everybody!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

CREATE PDF:

```
public void createPDF() {  

            Document doc = new Document();        
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";       

                File dir = new File(path);
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

                //File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
                File file = new File(dir, "ciccia.pdf");

                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);        
                PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

                // open the document
                doc.open();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                        .getResources(), R.drawable.androtuto);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                // add image to document
                doc.add(myImg);        

                Paragraph spazio = new Paragraph(" ");
                Font spazioFont = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                spazio.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                spazio.setFont(spazioFont);

                Paragraph pTavolo = new Paragraph("numero tavolo: "+numeroTavolo);
                Font paraFontTavolo = new Font(Font.COURIER);
                pTavolo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                pTavolo.setFont(paraFontTavolo);        

                // add paragraph to document
                doc.add(pTavolo);        

                Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(string);
                System.out.println(string);
                Font paraFont = new Font(Font.COURIER);
                p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p1.setFont(paraFont);        

                doc.add(p1);
                Paragraph pizzeOrdinate = new Paragraph("Pizze ordinate: "+string2);

                Font paraFontPizzeOrdinate = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                pizzeOrdinate.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                pizzeOrdinate.setFont(paraFontPizzeOrdinate);

                doc.add(pizzeOrdinate);

                // add paragraph to document

                Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("TOTALE Pizze: "+totalepizze);

                Font paraFont3 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                p3.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p3.setFont(paraFont3);

                doc.add(p3);        
                doc.add(spazio);
                doc.add(spazio);        

                Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("BIBITE ordinate"+string4);
                System.out.println(string4);        

                Font paraFont2 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p2.setFont(paraFont2);

                doc.add(p2);

                Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("TOTALE Bibite: "+totalebibite);        
                Font paraFont4 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                p4.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p4.setFont(paraFont4);

                doc.add(p4);        
                doc.add(spazio);
                doc.add(spazio);

                int costoTotale= totalepizze+totalebibite;
                Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph("TOTALE : "+costoTotale);

                Font paraFont5 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                p5.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p5.setFont(paraFont5);

                doc.add(p5);

               /* Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("TOTALE: "+tot);

                Font paraFont3 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                p3.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                p3.setFont(paraFont3);

                doc.add(p3);*/        

                stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                        .getResources(), R.drawable.android);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                // add image to document
                doc.add(myImg);

                // set footer
                Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Pied de page ");
                HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
                doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

            } catch (DocumentException de) {
                // Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
               /* Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de.getMessage());*/
                Log.e("PDFCreator", "some message", de);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //  Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
                Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + e.getMessage());       

            } finally {
                doc.close();
            }        
        }
```

VIEW PDF:

```
 public void viewPDF() {
        String path = "/sdcard/droidText/ciccia.pdf";   

        try {
    File targetFile = new File(path);
    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setPackage("com.hp.android.print");
    //intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
    final String appPackageName="com.hp.android.print";
            try{
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" +appPackageName)));
            }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfer){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +appPackageName)));
    }
        }
    }
```

ANDROID MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Is it causing a crash? Have you looked at other posts regarding this error, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null)?

Comment: it doesn't open pdf with ePrint hp....

Comment: Are you certain that that's the problem? Have you tested your code elsewhere? Your `path` doesn't look right to me. Have you checked if `targetFile.exists()`? You shouldn't be using hard-coded paths, anyway.

Comment: doesn't work any devices....so in targetFile.exists() what i must put?

Comment: Look at how you're creating `file` in your `createPDF()` method. That's how you need to create `targetFile` in the `viewPDF()` method.

Comment: i need save pdf file in "archive-->documents" but i have not sd card...so how can i do it?

Comment: Can You help me please?

Comment: I've told you what you need to do, but that relies on your `createPDF()` method having run successfully. Are you sure your PDF is being created?

Comment: If i Save on sd card work but i Need to save it without sd card...with this code that i edited it works with SD...