# Getting error message (E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null ) when trying to add an object to a static List

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, error-handling

I'm new in coding. I want to add a myObjectChild to a static list that is declared in the class of MyObjectChild. I get an error when trying to add to the static list, but it works fine to add the same object to a list declared in the method. I don't know what's wrong. I want to add the object to the static list. I created the list in the method only to test if the problem was with the object or with the adding to the static list and it seems that the problem is when adding to the static list. Can someone help me?? Here is my code:

```
public class MyObjectChild extends MyObject {

 int id;
 String name;
 static List <MyObject> staticList = new ArrayList<>(); 
 static String jsonStaticList = null;



   @Override
   public void addToList ()  {

     List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

     try {
         list.add(this); // this works when running the app
         }  catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error", "Didn’t add MyObject to the methodList ");  }

     try {
         staticList.add(this); // this doesn't work when running the app
         }  catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace(); } //got this message: E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 
}
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: it simply doesn't add the object to the static list and goes to catch Exception e.

Comment: use `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block to get the error messages.

Comment: The code you posted, once corrected, e.g. for `String` instead of `string`, does not throw any exceptions at all.

Comment: @John Joe - using the e.printStackTrace()  I got this error message: E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null.  - but only when trying to add the object to the staticList. full stackTrace:  07-26 01:28:55.810    1608-1608/com.ullaapps.calculaprazocpc E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: Please edit your post by adding full stackTrace.

Comment: the full stackTrace is: 07-26 01:54:59.855  30911-30911/com.ullaapps.calculaprazocpc E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: That is not a stack trace, and it is not edited into your question, and `mView == null` has nothing to do with this code whatsoever.

Comment: i' reading some posts that says that's a bug that occurs when running apps in Samsung devices https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null  - I haven't another device to test it now. So I will try it later and see if that's the problem. Doesn't make much sense, but can be. My code is more extense thant that , but the problem is exactly in this part. Thanx for you trying to help .

Comment: Err, no. You clearly do have an `mView == null` problem but it doesn't have anything to do with this code.

Comment: Editing your title is fine, but you were asked for the complete stack trace 24 hours ago, and several times since. Where is it? At present there is *no evidence* of a problem in this code.

Comment: I'm new in coding. Do it as a  hobby, I don't understand what you mean with the complete stack trace?? Is that whats comes before and after..like this : :07-27 02:01:42.290      582-582/com.ullaapps.calculaprazocpc D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
07-27 02:01:42.295      582-582/com.ullaapps.calculaprazocpc E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-27 02:01:44.450      582-582/com.ullaapps.calculaprazocpc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 322K, 12% free 11930K/13408K, paused 23ms, total 23ms ... ??

Comment: It is the result of calling `printStackTrace()`. This seems rather obvious. The stack trace would need to contain a reference to the line of your code that you claim is throwing the exception for your claim to be valid. At present there is nothing to connect them.

Comment: well I took a way around and solved  my problem changing my code -  declaring the List in my activity and it worked as I needed. Was having to much headache with this issue. I will delete this post. I think that it will not help anyone.