# sendUserActionEvent() returned

Tags: java, android, popupwindow, dismiss

I got the following error when a popup dismisses using android studio. The code works OK, but the following error appears on logcat:

```
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
```

java code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View popupView = layoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dayview_popup,null);
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

....

int[] loc_int = new int[2];
try {
    view.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {}

Rect location = new Rect();
location.left = loc_int[0];
location.top = loc_int[1];
location.right = location.left + view.getWidth();
location.bottom = location.top + view.getHeight();

popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, location.right, location.bottom);

View container = (View) popupWindow.getContentView().getParent();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) cntx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
p.dimAmount = 0.7f;
wm.updateViewLayout(container, p);
```

Comment: Not sure, but see if this helps:https://medium.com/@WeselyOng/a-nasty-webview-error-comes-along-with-senduseractionevent-error-82887cdb1627 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476427/e-viewrootimpl-senduseractionevent-returned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sendUserActionEvent() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476427/e-viewrootimpl-senduseractionevent-returned

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the code and writing it again. May be Cut, close project, open project and paste that section back.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely the issue with the device rather than the app. Your app is fine. Similar issue was raised before: [sendUserActionEvent() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028666/senduseractionevent-is-null)

Thanks.